# fluent table display/retrieve item from another model (Icollection) (related table) in html

Tags: asp.net, many-to-many, entity, fluent-interface

I have 2 tables Actors, Movies

```
var Movie = new List<Movie>
            {
            new Movie{MovieID=1,Title="Chemistry",Date="2013-09-01", Budget=10000,  Actors = new List<Actor>() },
            new Movie{MovieID=2,Title="Chemistry Double",Date="2014-09-01", Budget=78600, Actors = new List<Actor>()}
            };
```

Entity automatically creates MovieActors table.
Of course I fill info with

```
Movies.Actor.Add (Actor[3]); //specific number
```

And Fluen API creates corresponding MovieActor table. That works.

I have Actor/views Index.cshtml

How can I display specific movie in actors table?

I create decision but this shows nothing but actors.name

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
       </td>

        <td>
            @foreach (var subitem in item.Movies)
            {
            Html.DisplayFor(Movies => subitem.MovieID);
            } 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
`}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Html.DisplayFor(Movies => subitem.MovieID);
```

I should add "@" character.

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(Movies => subitem.MovieID);
```

And all works. No logical errors was.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit code:

```
var Movie = new List<Movie>
        {
        new Movie{MovieID=1,Title="Chemistry",Date="2013-09-01", Budget=10000,  Actors = new List<Actor>() },
        new Movie{MovieID=2,Title="Chemistry Double",Date="2014-09-01", Budget=78600, Actors = new List<Actor>()}
        };
```

`new List<Actor>()` is null. Actors must be filled from Actor table. edit like this:

```
new Movie{MovieID=1,Title="Chemistry",Date="2013-09-01", Budget=10000,  Actors = db.Actors().tolist()}
```

db.Actors() is Actor table.

Comment: No. It is not null. I just reduced my post. I realize adding by Movies.Actor.Add (Actor); And this creates MovieActor table automatically through fluent API. But I can`t retrieve this info and get it to html.

Comment: No. I have no problem, with filling my movie table with some actor or actors in list form. I post it.  Later I would post my specific code. Anyway, thanks.Problema is output list of movie actors with other data to html.